# Why will my OpenGL ES textures not render properly?

Tags: opengl-es, render

Im using OpenGL for an app that im trying to make. I've been learning from the apress book Beggining iPhone Games Development.

The problem I have is that a texturedQuad which is a subclass of my mesh class doesn't seem to be rendering properly. (Although it works in the simulator.) The quad renders as just a plain colors that I have set in the texturedQuad class and doesn't seem to be rendering the texture.

This is in a class that is called MenuOptionObject.m which is the actual object that I'm trying to render which I feel is similar to the spaceShip.m file used in the examples. That file did work so I dont get why this wont when I'm using virtually the same 'engine' if you could call it that.

I have a feeling I'm missing something blatent. The examples I worked on worked. I also have a class called texturedButton that does work and also uses the texturedQuad.

Heres the mesh.m code:

```
 #import "Mesh.h"
#import "MaterialController.h"
#import "TexturedQuad.h"


@implementation Mesh

@synthesize vertexCount,vertexSize,colorSize,renderStyle,vertexes,colors;

- (id)initWithVertexes:(CGFloat*)verts 
           vertexCount:(NSInteger)vertCount 
            vertexSize:(NSInteger)vertSize
           renderStyle:(GLenum)style;
{
    self = [super init];
    if (self != nil) 
    {
        self.vertexes = verts;
        self.vertexCount = vertCount;
        self.vertexSize = vertSize;
        self.renderStyle = style;
    }
    return self;
}

// called once every frame
-(void)render
{
    glDisableClientState(GL_TEXTURE_COORD_ARRAY);
    glDisable(GL_TEXTURE_2D);
    // load arrays into the engine
    glVertexPointer(vertexSize, GL_FLOAT, 0, vertexes);
    glEnableClientState(GL_VERTEX_ARRAY);
    glColorPointer(colorSize, GL_FLOAT, 0, colors); 
    glEnableClientState(GL_COLOR_ARRAY);

    //render
    glDrawArrays(renderStyle, 0, vertexCount);  
}


+(CGRect)meshBounds:(Mesh*)mesh scale:(BBPoint)scale
{
    if (mesh == nil) return CGRectZero;
    // need to run through my vertexes and find my extremes
    if (mesh.vertexCount < 2) return CGRectZero;
    CGFloat xMin,yMin,xMax,yMax;
    xMin = xMax = mesh.vertexes[0];
    yMin = yMax = mesh.vertexes[1];
    NSInteger index;
    for (index = 0; index < mesh.vertexCount; index++) {
        NSInteger position = index * mesh.vertexSize;
        if (xMin > mesh.vertexes[position] * scale.x) xMin = mesh.vertexes[position] * scale.x;
        if (xMax < mesh.vertexes[position] * scale.x) xMax = mesh.vertexes[position] * scale.x;
        if (yMin > mesh.vertexes[position + 1] * scale.y) yMin = mesh.vertexes[position + 1] * scale.y;
        if (yMax < mesh.vertexes[position + 1] * scale.y) yMax = mesh.vertexes[position + 1] * scale.y;
    }
    CGRect meshBounds = CGRectMake(xMin, yMin, xMax - xMin, yMax - yMin);
    if (CGRectGetWidth(meshBounds) < 1.0) meshBounds.size.width = 1.0;
    if (CGRectGetHeight(meshBounds) < 1.0) meshBounds.size.height = 1.0;
    return meshBounds;
}

- (void) dealloc
{
    [super dealloc];
}



@end
```

Heres the texturedQuad.m code:

```
    #import "TexturedQuad.h"

static CGFloat TexturedQuadVertexes[8] = 
{
    -0.5,-0.5, 0.5,-0.5, 
    -0.5,0.5, 0.5,0.5
};
static CGFloat TexturedQuadColorValues[16] = 
{
    1.0,1.0,1.0,1.0, 
    1.0,1.0,1.0,1.0, 
    1.0,1.0,1.0,1.0, 
    1.0,1.0,1.0,1.0
};

@implementation TexturedQuad

@synthesize uvCoordinates,materialKey;

- (id) init
{
    self = [super initWithVertexes:TexturedQuadVertexes vertexCount:4 vertexSize:2 renderStyle:GL_TRIANGLE_STRIP];
    if (self != nil) {
        // 4 vertexes
        uvCoordinates = (CGFloat *) malloc(8 * sizeof(CGFloat));
        colors = TexturedQuadColorValues;
        colorSize = 4;
    }
    return self;
}

// called once every frame
-(void)render
{
    glVertexPointer(vertexSize, GL_FLOAT, 0, vertexes);
    glEnableClientState(GL_VERTEX_ARRAY);
    glColorPointer(colorSize, GL_FLOAT, 0, colors); 
    glEnableClientState(GL_COLOR_ARRAY);

    if (materialKey != nil) {
        [[MaterialController sharedController] bindMaterial:materialKey];

        glEnableClientState(GL_TEXTURE_COORD_ARRAY); 
        glTexCoordPointer(2, GL_FLOAT, 0, uvCoordinates);
    } 
    //render
    glDrawArrays(renderStyle, 0, vertexCount);  
}


- (void) dealloc
{
    free(uvCoordinates);
    [super dealloc];
}

@end
```

And lastly for the MenuOptionObject.m:

```
#import "MenuOptionObject.h"
#import "MaterialController.h"
#import "MenuSceneController.h"

@implementation MenuOptionObject
@synthesize bounds, circleBouncePoint;

-(id)initWithQuad:(NSString *)quad
{
    self = [super init];
    if (self != nil)
    {
        self.mesh = [[MaterialController sharedController] quadFromAtlasKey:quad];
    }
    return self;
}

// called once when the object is first created.
-(void)awake
{   
    self.scale = BBPointMake(28.0, 28.0, 1.0);
    self.sceneController = (SceneController *)[MenuSceneController sharedController];
}

-(void)update
{
    [super update];
    //[self sideCollisionUpdates];
    //[self circleCollisionUpdates];
}


-(void)dealloc
{
    [sceneController release];
    [super dealloc];
}

@end
```

Comment: See also http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6246340/opengl-es-1-1-wont-render-textures (I'm not totally sure about the difference, too long post).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Answer turned out to be the even though my texture was called menuAtlas both in the file manager at the side and in the code it wouldn't work so changing both to mA worked. I don't understand why but I have a suspicion that it involves something to do with caching.

Answer (score 3):

Did you remember calling `glEnable(GL_TEXTURE_2D)` before rendering the textured geometry?

Comment: It's done in the bindMaterial method in the materialController `-(void)bindMaterial:(NSString*)materialKey { NSNumber * numberObj = [materialLibrary objectForKey:materialKey]; if (numberObj == nil) return; GLuint textureID = [numberObj unsignedIntValue]; glEnable(GL_TEXTURE_2D); glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_2D, textureID); }` Thanks for going through it all and responding though