# OpenGL ES 1.1 wont render textures?

Tags: iphone, ios, opengl-es, render

Right, I posted a similar question, Ive tried completely rebuilding the files and what happens now is textures aren't rendering at all. The image is 512x512. For some reason the texture works on simulator but not my iPod.

In a class called EAGLView there is, beginDraw and finishDraw which are called at the beggining and end of my game loop. Layout subviews is called when I create the view.

```
-(void)beginDraw
{
    // Make sure that you are drawing to the current context
    [EAGLContext setCurrentContext:context];
    glBindFramebufferOES(GL_FRAMEBUFFER_OES, viewFramebuffer);
    // make sure we are in model matrix mode and clear the frame
    glMatrixMode(GL_MODELVIEW);
    glClear(GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT);
    // set a clean transform
    glLoadIdentity();   
}

-(void)finishDraw
{
    glBindRenderbufferOES(GL_RENDERBUFFER_OES, viewRenderbuffer);
    [context presentRenderbuffer:GL_RENDERBUFFER_OES];  
}

- (void)layoutSubviews 
{
    [EAGLContext setCurrentContext:context];
    [self destroyFramebuffer];
    [self createFramebuffer];
    [self setupViewLandscape];
}

- (BOOL)createFramebuffer {    
    glGenFramebuffersOES(1, &viewFramebuffer);
    glGenRenderbuffersOES(1, &viewRenderbuffer);

    glBindFramebufferOES(GL_FRAMEBUFFER_OES, viewFramebuffer);
    glBindRenderbufferOES(GL_RENDERBUFFER_OES, viewRenderbuffer);

    [context renderbufferStorage:GL_RENDERBUFFER_OES fromDrawable:(CAEAGLLayer*)self.layer];
    glFramebufferRenderbufferOES(GL_FRAMEBUFFER_OES, GL_COLOR_ATTACHMENT0_OES, GL_RENDERBUFFER_OES, viewRenderbuffer);

    glGetRenderbufferParameterivOES(GL_RENDERBUFFER_OES, GL_RENDERBUFFER_WIDTH_OES, &backingWidth);
    glGetRenderbufferParameterivOES(GL_RENDERBUFFER_OES, GL_RENDERBUFFER_HEIGHT_OES, &backingHeight);

    if (USE_DEPTH_BUFFER) {
        glGenRenderbuffersOES(1, &depthRenderbuffer);
        glBindRenderbufferOES(GL_RENDERBUFFER_OES, depthRenderbuffer);
        glRenderbufferStorageOES(GL_RENDERBUFFER_OES, GL_DEPTH_COMPONENT16_OES, backingWidth, backingHeight);
        glFramebufferRenderbufferOES(GL_FRAMEBUFFER_OES, GL_DEPTH_ATTACHMENT_OES, GL_RENDERBUFFER_OES, depthRenderbuffer);
    }

    if(glCheckFramebufferStatusOES(GL_FRAMEBUFFER_OES) != GL_FRAMEBUFFER_COMPLETE_OES) {
        NSLog(@"failed to make complete framebuffer object %x", glCheckFramebufferStatusOES(GL_FRAMEBUFFER_OES));
        return NO;
    }

    return YES;
}
```

My texturedQuad render method is

```
-(void)render
{
    glVertexPointer(vertexSize, GL_FLOAT, 0, vertexes);
    glEnableClientState(GL_VERTEX_ARRAY);
    glColorPointer(colorSize, GL_FLOAT, 0, colors); 
    glEnableClientState(GL_COLOR_ARRAY);    

    if (materialKey != nil) {
        [[MaterialController sharedMaterialController] bindMaterial:materialKey];

        glEnableClientState(GL_TEXTURE_COORD_ARRAY); 
        glTexCoordPointer(2, GL_FLOAT, 0, uvCoordinates);
    } 
    //render
    glDrawArrays(renderStyle, 0, vertexCount);  
}
```

Also here is the bindMaterial method:

```
-(void)bindMaterial:(NSString*)materialKey 
{
    NSNumber *numberObj = [materialLibrary objectForKey:materialKey];
    if (numberObj == nil) return;
    GLuint textureID = [numberObj unsignedIntValue];

    glEnable(GL_TEXTURE_2D);
    glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_2D, textureID);
}
```

It is called when my sceneObject is rendered:
(TexturedQuad is a subclass of mesh)

```
-(void)render
{
    if (!mesh || !active) return; // if we do not have a mesh, no need to render
    // clear the matrix
    glPushMatrix();
    glLoadIdentity();
    glMultMatrixf(matrix);
    [mesh render];  
    glPopMatrix();
}
```

And lastly my Test class:
Awake is called when the object is added to the scene

```
-(void)awake
{
    self.mesh = [[MaterialController sharedMaterialController] quadFromAtlasKey:@"boxNotSelected"];
    self.scale = BBPointMake(50.0, 50.0, 1.0);
}
```

Thanks for taking your time to read this and thanks if you offer any help =]

Comment: See also http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6239374/why-will-my-opengl-es-textures-not-render-properly (I'm not totally sure about the difference, too long post).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Answer turned out to be the even though my texture was called menuAtlas both in the file manager at the side and in the code it wouldn't work so changing both to mA worked. I don't understand why but I have a suspicion that it involves something to do with caching.

Answer (score 1):

Are you making any calls to glTexParameter anywhere, and are you creating mip maps? It could just be that the GPU is sampling a map you haven't supplied. What happens if you set MIN_FILTER to GL_NEAREST or GL_LINEAR?

Comment: No, I'm not using mip mapping at the moment. (I don't know how yet, but I'll probably  Setting MIN_FILTER didn't help but may in other cases? I dont know. And I've found out that the code works for what I wanted to do, the problem is that my picture file was called MenuAtlas.png and my information stored at menuAtlas.plist the way that I called it used menu and not Menu, (I realised this after readingthat said iPhone is case sensitive). I changed this which still didnt work. But then changed all to mA (so it stands for the same thing) and it worked! I haven't the first idea why though.

Comment: Oh, well, I'm glad it works! For the future, not setting MIN_FILTER will leave it on its default value of NEAREST_MIPMAP_LINEAR. So if you don't have mip maps supplied (whether manually or automatically) then when your geometry becomes sufficiently small that it doesn't want to use the full size image, it'll display one of the smaller ones, but they're all blank so the area where your texture should be will be blank. It's a mistake I make alarmingly often.

Comment: Awsome, sorry for such a slow responce, I can see that saving me some problems in the future :) Thanks for the help